# Android link PHP to MySQL to login in app

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, authentication

I'm trying to understand how can I link by Android App to PHP/MySQL in order to get a login from a user that is already on a database.

I found that one way of doing it was through going to PHP pages, sending the inputed data from the app and post it on parameters on PHP, and PHP itself should look for the user references and return if the user either exists or not.

However, every place I look for how to do this it is too much either complicated or not well explained.
So I'm looking for a way to do this, and if you know some tutorial or well commented code that you could provide for me to learn it would be very useful to me. Or any of you could teach me how to do it or where to start learning would be great.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: refer this one maybe helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363127/connect-android-app-in-my-mobile-to-phpmyadmin/18364848#18364848

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of interaction I use this code:

```
public static String httpPost(String address, List<NameValuePair> parameters) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(address);

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        reader = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(inputStream)));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
            if (inputStream != null)
                inputStream.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

You have to pass this function a `String` which is the URL of the PHP script, and a list of `NameValuePair`s containing the data you want to pass to the script, and it returns the answer from the server.

If you want to use it for login, you can use something like that:

```
public boolean login(String username, String passwd) {
    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username);
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwd);

    String result = httpPost("http://test.com/login.php", parameters);

    return result.equals("ok");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers mentioning about posting Input data to your PHP web page. How ever you can also follow another approach.

In this approach you will need a webview loaded initially(assuming login is needed for all activities). In the web view simply load the web page, say `http://www.example.com/login?device=mobile` Once user has logged in successfully, assuming that website would load a logged in page, `example.com/user` you need to check if this was the URL which is opened. Then it means that login was completed successfully. Then you could proceed to next activity in your App.

[Reference](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)